# when ssh schtasks executes the bat script, the task does not run or the result is not seen

Tags: ssh, remote-server, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to run bat scripts on a remote server via ssh schtasks, which includes the execution of sas programs. This way I can create a program task that runs periodically. But after the schtasks is successfully created, it always fails to run to get the output file I want.

In the process of trying, I encountered the following problems:

1. The script can be successfully run on the remote server through ssh and get the output results, but the bat script using schtasks can not achieve the same effect.
2. When checking the details of this task, I found that the user running this task is my account instead of system, but when I change the parameter /ru to system, the access is denied.

Now I am not sure if it is because of the account permissions or other reasons? What should I do if it is account access?